# Android handle data in Fragments on back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have 2 main Fragments in my `MainActivity`

```
  [A]  ,  [B]
```

and Fragment `[A]` has 3 more Fragments

```
  [1] , [2] , [3]
```

And Fragment `[1]` has  also a  `Fragment` and that `Fragment` also has one more `Fragment` and this chain goes on.
 Now when we press `Back` button of device, we first check current `Fragment` in `MainActivity` and work as :

```
if (fragment!=null &&fragment.getClass()== Fragment3.class) {
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment tFragment = new Fragment2();
ft.replace(R.id.container, tFragment);
ft.commit();
}
```

But this isn't a right way to do so I don't get data of `Fragment` `[1]` which came from `Fragment` `[A]` using `Bundle`. Please provide a proper way to do this.

I have tried also :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

It works for coming into previous `Fragment` but I cannot called `onResume` method of that Fragment.
  So I wanna know how I can use Back pressed button to handle the data.